# A simple regex that is performing very badly on Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a simple Ruby regex that is taking very long to compute:

```
"fußball "*20 =~ /^([\S\s]{1000})/i
```

If I remove `/i` flag it works very fast. Why is it running so slowly? (I didn't wait for execution to finish)

I know this regex might not make sense, but I'm wondering what is under the hood.

---

Bug report: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14418

Comment: It also works when you decrease multiplier in ```"fußball "*20```

Comment: It gets slow if the quantifier value exceeds the string length, e.g. `{161}` and above for `"fußball "*20` (which has a length of 160).

Comment: That's really odd – it seems to be related to `ß`. If you replace that character with another one (multi-byte or not), the regex behaves as expected. Adding more `ß`'s makes it slower.

Comment: Do you gus think it might be Ruby bug?

Comment: This is a bug if the performance differs.

Comment: There is something curious. `"fußball "*20 =~ /^([\S\s]{1000})/i` should be equivalent to `"fußball "*20 =~ /^.{1000}/i` and that option does not take that long – ana06 14 mins ago

Comment: I would report it to Ruby, it seems to be a bug

Comment: The issue is either with the fact that the `\s` and `\S` are expanded into real character sets inside a character class, or with the case unfolding function. An expression that works the same but should be quick is `/^.{1000}/mi` as `.` with `m` modifier matches any char.

Comment: Runtime is O(3^n) where n is your multiplier. I tried `(0..20).each { |n| puts Benchmark.measure { "fußball "*n =~ /^([\S\s]{1000})/i } }` and from one n to the next, the time tripled. All characters I found causing this behavior: `ßΐΰẞᾀᾁᾂᾃᾄᾅᾆᾇᾈᾉᾊᾋᾌᾍᾎᾏᾐᾑᾒᾓᾔᾕᾖᾗᾘᾙᾚᾛᾜᾝᾞᾟᾠᾡᾢᾣᾤᾥᾦᾧᾨᾩᾪᾫᾬᾭᾮᾯᾳᾼῃῌΐΰῳῼ‌​ﬅﬆ`. Also: characters causing O(2^n) behavior: `İŉſǰևẖẗẘẙẚὐὒὔὖᾲᾴᾶᾷῂῄῆῇῒῖῗῢῤῦῧῲῴῶῷﬀﬁﬂﬃﬄﬓﬔﬕﬖﬗ`. Among these, `ſ` is special - it's twice as fast as all the others. (Sorry for previously saying cubic/quadratic about these, silly mistake.)

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow is the right forum for bug reports

Answer (score 1):

By default `.` doesn't match newlines. `[\s\S]` is a hack around that problem. In Ruby you can use the /m flag to make the dot match all characters. It's in the documentation [Ruby Metacharacters and Escapes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Metacharacters+and+Escapes)

`[\S\s]` for an unknown reason is very slow but you can change it to `"fußball "*20 =~ /^(.{1000})/mi` that does the same but faster

Comment: And how does this relate to the question? Could you clarify?

Comment: You can change the regex to `"fußball "*20 =~ /^(.{1000})/mi` that does the same but faster.